# What hardware should I use to connect a 4x6 beam to the top of a 4x4 post for a swing set?

Tags: hardware, swing

What hardware should I use to connect a 4x6 to the top of a 4x4?

Edit: To assuage some confusion, I already have a bracket for the a-frame end, the aptly-named swing set bracket. What I need is a bracket for the circled connection. Yes, it's for a swing set. I could've sworn including a picture and circling exactly what I'm talking about and putting in the swing tag would've helped, but it's apparently still pretty confusing ‍♂️

Like this:

[image: Like this]

Comment: What kinds of loads is this expected to carry? For half a ton of rainwater (dead weight, spread across four uprights), I used lap joints and construction screws, though lag bolts might have been a better choice. If this is intended to carry a swing, forces go in other directions and are dynamic.

Comment: Yes, as shown, it's a swing. No rainwater will be an issue. I had hoped using a picture of literally exactly what I'm building would help, but I guess not? Which is why I I need to know what kind of connector to use. The other end is easy enough, they make aptly named swing set brackets in the right size for the two 4x4 and one 4x6 beams, but not at this end.

Comment: Trimming away the other part of the structure removed some of the context.

Comment: I don't think so. I circled the connection I need a bracket for, plus, the "swing" tag it wouldn't let me post without

Comment: Consider sandwiching the beam between the A-frame members like most other designs do. This transfers some load to the friction connection rather than relying solely on the shear fasteners in the crossblock.

Comment: Are you sure you just want a 4x4 for that post?  Any kind of swing action is going to put a lateral load on the post and cause it to sway back and forth.

Comment: Considering the play structure is built on 4x4s, yes. The 4x4 moving isn't what's worrying me since it's just one of like 8 others that the play structure is built on, rather the connection between the 4x4 and the 4x6, which is why I came here to ask what kind of bracket there is for doing it

Answer (score 2):

I would place 18" 2x4s on each side of that connection point and use 5 through bolts, washers and nuts to secure it. Put 2 bolts above the lap and three bolts below, all staggered. Angle cut the bottom of each 2x4 for appearance.

Comment: I edited that into my answer.

Comment: OP could also get some 1/4" steel plates made and do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

I would build this out with the A frame on both ends if the horizontal beam. That will provide much better support for the types of forces that swings exert on to the beam. You can do this easily and effectively uncouple the swing set from what appears to be a corner of a raised deck.

Future flexibility is a strong factor here. Families needing back yard swings change with the passage of years and moving, selling or removing the free-standing swing structure will be much easier.

Comment: The free standing play structure is built already, and the swing beam is being attached to one end of it. Why is everyone more worried about what's not shown in the picture I found on the internet instead of what I'm actually asking, which I circled? I'm so confused. I would rather not tear down what I've already built.

Comment: My suggestion still stands. The separate swing structure with two A frames is far superior and far far more flexible for future considerations. Sorry if you do not want to hear about better ways of doing things.

Comment: I came here asking a specific question, not for your suggestion, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [this.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07BPMNSQN)

The first comment shows a pic of the unit attached to an upright member as you have. With the comment that it works great for the grand childrens' swing.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, but this seems to be for attaching the 4x6 to one side of the 4x4, not on top of it like I'm looking for. I'm sure there's a Simpson bracket that does what I need but I guess I can't find the right search terms to find it.

Comment: If the post isn't there yet, make it taller and attache to the side.

Comment: If you're in the US, search home depot's site for "simpson strong-tie 4x6" and you'll get a whole list. Including this one: https://www.homedepot.com/p/Simpson-Strong-Tie-EPCZ-ZMAX-Galvanized-End-Post-Cap-for-4x-Nominal-Lumber-EPC4Z/205694643

Comment: The post is there already. I'm adding a swing set to a play set. Are you saying it will be better to attach it to the side instead of on top? The bracket aghast suggested doesn't look as strong as the one you suggested, but neither appears to allow through bolts to be used, and that worries me. I'm already using through bolts on all the other brackets, including on the a-frame side. I feel better about the stability of anything that uses through bolts.

Comment: My thought is that the act of swinging is more likely to make the beam move off the top of a post. If attached to the side the weight is supported by bolts. ( you can use a couple of through bolts and one through the beam.)  The bolts will hold the weight of the beam and quite a few kids swinging unless they bring their pet elephants with them.  2 of the first 3 comments were people that used the bracket for a swing set.  So there is real world use that supports it.

Comment: Remember the bracket has holes. What you put through those holes to attach it is up to you.

Comment: The small holes look like they're for screws, and the two large holes are offset, so it wouldn't be through bolts unfortunately.

Comment: I don’t have the hardware in hand, so am speculating… but I sincerely doubt that the through bolt holes are offset. That’s not how Simpson hardware rolls. And lots of good screws are astonishingly strong. (All that said, I still like the 2x4 — or 4x4 if you want — sandwich by @jack.)

Comment: Well in the picture it's offset, and the reviews say the same thing. It's not usually how Simpson brackets are, I agree, but in this case it seems they decided to mix it up just to mess with us. It looks like a generic version of the same bracket has aligned holes for a bolt, but still just the 6 screw holes to mount it to the 4x4, so even that one worries me.

Comment: Well, just fyi, not that anyone's still bothering with this question, but it turns out that the generic one has offset holes too. It says 5mm. I'm guessing the Simpson bracket has the same offset.